# Python, Theano - ValueError: Input dimension mis-match

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, lasagne

I have built a DNN in Theano based on the mnist.py example in Lasagne.
I am trying to train a neural network made by a single hidden layer first, defined as

```
def build_first_auto(input_var=None):

    l_input=lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None, 1, 48, 1), input_var=input_var)
    l_hidden1=lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(l_input,num_units=256,nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.sigmoid,W=lasagne.init.GlorotUniform())

    return l_hidden1
```

This is used inside

```
from load_dataset import load_dataset
from build_DNNs import build_first_auto

import sys
import os
import time

import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

import lasagne
import scipy.io as sio

def iterate_minibatches(inputs, targets, batchsize, shuffle=False):

    assert len(inputs) == len(targets)
    if shuffle:
        indices = np.arange(len(inputs))
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
    for start_idx in range(0, len(inputs) - batchsize + 1, batchsize):
        if shuffle:
            excerpt = indices[start_idx:start_idx + batchsize]
        else:
                excerpt = slice(start_idx, start_idx + batchsize)
        yield inputs[excerpt], targets[excerpt]


def train_autoencoder(num_epochs):

    Xtrain, ytrain = load_dataset()

# Prepare Theano variables for inputs and targets
    input_var = T.tensor4('inputs')
    target_var = T.matrix('targets')
# Create neural network model
    network = build_first_auto(input_var)

    prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network)
    params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(network, trainable=True)

    loss = lasagne.objectives.binary_crossentropy(prediction, target_var)
    loss = loss.mean()

    updates = lasagne.updates.nesterov_momentum(loss, params, learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)
    np.save('params', params)

#Monitoring the training
    test_prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network, deterministic=True)
    test_loss = lasagne.objectives.categorical_crossentropy(test_prediction,target_var)
    test_loss = test_loss.mean()

    test_acc = T.mean(T.eq(T.argmax(test_prediction,axis=1),target_var),dtype=theano.config.floatX)


#Compile    
    train_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], loss, updates=updates, on_unused_input='ignore' ) #on_unused_input='ignore'

# Compile a second function computing the validation loss and accuracy:
    val_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], [test_loss, test_acc])


#Training
    print("Starting training...")
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # In each epoch, we do a full pass over the training data:
        train_err = 0
        train_batches = 0
        start_time = time.time()
        for batch in iterate_minibatches(Xtrain, ytrain, 30821, shuffle=True):
            inputs, targets = batch

            train_err += train_fn(inputs, targets)
            train_batches += 1


    # And a full pass over the validation data:
        val_err = 0
        val_acc = 0
        val_batches = 0
        for batch in iterate_minibatches(Xtrain, ytrain, 30821, shuffle=False):
            inputs, targets = batch
            err, acc = val_fn(inputs, targets)
            val_err += err
            val_acc += acc
            val_batches += 1


    # Then we print the results for this epoch:
        print("Epoch {} of {} took {:.3f}s".format(
        epoch + 1, num_epochs, time.time() - start_time))
        print("  training loss:\t\t{:.6f}".format(train_err / train_batches))
        print("  validation loss:\t\t{:.6f}".format(val_err / val_batches))
        print("  validation accuracy:\t\t{:.2f} %".format(
        val_acc / val_batches * 100))
```

The loss function is the binary cross-entropy. The problem is that I am getting an error related to the arrays dimensions:

> ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[1].shape[1] = 1, input[3].shape[1] = 256)
>
> Apply node that caused the error: Elemwise{Composite{(((i0 * i1 * (i2 - scalar_sigmoid(i3))) / i4) - ((i0 * i5 * scalar_sigmoid(i3)) / i4))}}(TensorConstant{(1, 1) of -1.0}, targets, TensorConstant{(1, 1) of 1.0}, Elemwise{Add}[(0, 0)].0, Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0, Elemwise{sub,no_inplace}.0)
>
> Toposort index: 17
>
> Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, (True, True)), TensorType(float64, matrix), TensorType(float64, (True, True)), TensorType(float64, matrix), TensorType(float64, (True, True)), TensorType(float64, matrix)]
>
> Inputs shapes: [(1, 1), (30821, 1), (1, 1), (30821, 256), (1, 1), (30821, 1)]
>
> Inputs strides: [(8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8), (2048, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8)]
>
> Inputs values: [array([[-1.]]), 'not shown', array([[ 1.]]), 'not shown', array([[ 30821.]]), 'not shown']
>
> Outputs clients: [[Dot22Scalar(InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0, Elemwise{Composite{(((i0 * i1 * (i2 - scalar_sigmoid(i3))) / i4) - ((i0 * i5 * scalar_sigmoid(i3)) / i4))}}.0, TensorConstant{0.01}), Sum{axis=[0], acc_dtype=float64}(Elemwise{Composite{(((i0 * i1 * (i2 - scalar_sigmoid(i3))) / i4) - ((i0 * i5 * scalar_sigmoid(i3)) / i4))}}.0)]]

As a hint I can say that the dimension of inputs is (30821, 1, 48, 1) and for targets (30821, 1).
I have read several pages about how to fix this error with reshape, but it doesn't work for my case.
Also defining target_var=T.matrix() instead of T.ivector() didn't help.
Setting a proper dimension for the hidden layer would work, but the functionality of this neural network should be independent by this number. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For your network, the output is 256-dim.
Since you are using binary cross-entropy loss function, I suppose you want to classify samples into 2 classes. You need a output layer with num_units=2 and softmax

```
def build_first_auto(input_var=None):
    l_input=lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None, 1, 48, 1),input_var=input_var)
    l_hidden1=lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(l_input,num_units=256,nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.sigmoid,W=lasagne.init.GlorotUniform())
    l_output=lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(l_hidden1,num_units=2,nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax,W=lasagne.init.GlorotUniform())

return l_output
```

This should work. If there is any problem, please let me know.